# SEO with angular.js application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, seo

In my application, I used angular.js as a client side technology. Now, I want my site to be SEO friendly - I found the solution, but I am little bit confused about it. Is sitemap.xml required or not for angular SEO?

Comment: Are you using Single page application mode ?

Comment: Just throwing it out there, [Prerender.io](https://prerender.io/) makes this pretty easy and supports a lot of common httpds through middleware.

Answer (score 0):

Yes absolutely you do this in Angular JS.

Within your website, use the hashbang or HTML5 URLS to point to the content--Google and Bing are smart enough to figure out that they're AJAX-generated pages.

Here is an example of a [sitemap.xml](https://github.com/yearofmoo-articles/AngularJS-SEO-Article/blob/master/sitemap.xml) entry for a AJAX webpage.

Answer (score 0):

For making AJAX application crawlable you need to use prerender which will automatically create static HTML snapshots for Google bots (see this article: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/learn-more).

Comment: Please include relevant portions from the link here

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You have to do this in Angular. and yes Sitemap.xml is also required for SEO.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, sitemap.xml required for angular SEO.